# react-three-fiber useContext outside of a canvas is not the same as what is inside of the canvas

Tags: reactjs, use-context, react-three-fiber

```
//App.tsx
import './App.css';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { Player } from './components/Player';
import { TCharacter } from './types';
import { Chat } from './components/Chat';
import { NetworkProvider } from './network/useSocket';
import { GUI, InnerGUI } from './components/GUI';
function App(props: { character?: TCharacter }) {
    const { character = 'butterfly' } = props
    return (
        <div id='canvas'>
            <NetworkProvider>
                <Canvas>
                    <ambientLight />
                    <Player character={character} position={[0, 1, 0]} speed={4} />
                    <InnerGUI />
                </Canvas>
                <Chat />
                <GUI />
            </NetworkProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In the code above, All 4 components(Chat, GUI, Player, InnerGUI) use a single socket that is created only one time in whole program.

```
import { useSocket } from "../network/useSocket"

const GUI = () => {
    const { socket } = useSocket()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`GUI SK: `, socket)
    }, [socket, socket?.connected])

    return <>
        <input type='button' value='GUI' style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, right: 0 }} />
    </>
}

const InnerGUI = () => {
    const { socket } = useSocket()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`innerGUI SK: `, socket)
    }, [socket, socket?.connected])

    return <Html>
        <input type='button' value='INNER GUI' />
    </Html>
}

const Chat = () => {
    const { socket } = useSocket()

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(`chatSK: `, socket)
    },[socket, socket?.connected])
...

const Player = (props: { character: 'bee' | 'butterfly', position: number[], speed?: number }) => {
    const { position, speed = 1 } = props
    const keyStat: KeyStat = useKeyboard()
    const [action, setAction] = useState('idle')
    const ref = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!)
    const modelRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!)
    const camRef = useRef<PerspectiveCameraImpl>(null!)
    const { socket } = useSocket()

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(`PlayerSK: `, socket)
    },[socket, socket?.connected])
...
```

But when I execute this code, components outside  uses useSocket hook well, but components inside  doesn't. When I print the socket that components have got, inside and outside are not the same.

Here's the output
[image]

React.StrictMode is off now. When React.StrictMode is on, socket is initiated twice.

And Here's the useSocket Code

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client'
import { IChat, IPlayerInfo } from '../types';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        chat: (msg: string) => void
    }
}
interface ISocketData {
    timestamp: number,
    payload: any
}

const NetworkContext = createContext<{ socket: Socket, playerList: { [key: string]: IPlayerInfo }, chatData: IChat | null }>({ socket: io(''), playerList: {}, chatData: null });
const NetworkProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket>(null!)
    const [socketConnected, setSocketConnected] = useState(false)
    const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState(new Date().getTime())
    const [playerList, setPlayerList] = useState<{ [key: string]: IPlayerInfo }>({})
    const [chatData, setChatData] = useState<IChat | null>(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        setSocket(io(`localhost:2002`))
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket) return;

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('socket connected')
            setSocketConnected(socket.connected);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('socket disconnected')
            setSocketConnected(socket.connected);
        });

        socket.on('update', (data: ISocketData) => {
            if (data.timestamp < timestamp) return
            setPlayerList(data.payload)
            setTimestamp(data.timestamp)
        })

        socket.on('chat', (data: IChat) => {
            setChatData(data)
        })
    }, [socket]);

    return <NetworkContext.Provider value={{ socket, playerList, chatData }} children={children} />
}

const useSocket = () => {
    const { socket, playerList, chatData } = useContext(NetworkContext)
    return { socket, playerList, chatData }
}

export { NetworkProvider, useSocket }
```